# How to pause a NSTimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a game which uses a timer. I want to make it so the user can select a button and it pauses that timer and when they click that button again, it will unpause that timer. I already have code to the timer, just need some help with the pausing the timer and the dual-action button.

Code to timer:

```
-(void)timerDelay {

    mainInt = 36;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(countDownDuration)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
}

-(void)countDownDuration {

    MainInt -= 1;

    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", MainInt];
    if (MainInt <= 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self delay];
    }

}
```

Comment: Marking TBlue's answer as correct was correct if it helped you. You don't have to edit that code into your question or add [SOLVED] in the title. I'd recommend reading the [help] to learn more about the proper ways of posting in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's very easy.

```
// Declare the following variables
BOOL ispaused;
NSTimer *timer;
int MainInt;

-(void)countUp {
    if (ispaused == NO) {
        MainInt +=1;
        secondField.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",MainInt];
    }
}

- (IBAction)start1Clicked:(id)sender {
    MainInt=0;
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countUp) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)pause1Clicked:(id)sender {
    ispaused = YES;
}

- (IBAction)resume1Clicked:(id)sender {
    ispaused = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no pause and resume functionality in NSTimer. You can impliment it like below code.

```
- (void)startTimer
{
    m_pTimerObject = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self  selector:@selector(fireTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)fireTimer:(NSTimer *)inTimer
{
    // Timer is fired.
}

- (void)resumeTimer
{
    if(m_pTimerObject)
    {
        [m_pTimerObject invalidate];
        m_pTimerObject = nil;        
    }
    m_pTimerObject = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self  selector:@selector(fireTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)pauseTimer
{
    [m_pTimerObject invalidate];
    m_pTimerObject = nil;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't pause, it just stops and restarts.

Comment: @CarlVeazey As the answer mentions, there is no "pause" functionality in `NSTimer`, so any answer (including the accepted one) must work around that fact.  This answer is better than the accepted one because it does not keep a timer which is doing nothing valuable running.  +1

Comment: @Nate the answers in the duplicate seem to work around this fact while still offering pause functionality. I don't think it's unreasonable to point that out.

Comment: @Nate Chandler, thanks for pointing that out. What I don't understand is the vote down on an answer which is clearly correct. There should be an explenation required when someone votes down an answer.